# Joomla 1.5 and PHP 5.3

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, php-5.3

I have one website which is using Joomla 1.5 and running in php 5.3 . It was running with PHP 5.2 version, but the hosting company now updated to PHP 5.3 .So Joomla is creating issues with it:

- I cannot access the menus and modules from admin side.

I have tried for a migration to Joomla 2.5 But as the site is installed with a number of third party extensions, it is not easy to migrate. So is there any patched or something that will help me to run Joomla 1.5 on PHP 5.3 and do migration on a later date?

Comment: Joomla 1.5 and PHP 5.3 should be fine.  What do you mean by "cannot access the menus and modules"?  Any error messages?  Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Warning: Parameter 4 to JHTMLMenu::treerecurse() expected to be a reference, value given in /web/content/libraries/joomla/html/html.php on line 87

Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /web/content/administrator/components/com_menus/models/list.php on line 143

Comment: these are some of the warning messages  i am getting. i am using 1.5.10

Comment: 16 versions behind the latest 1.5 series version? not very good lol. always ensure you are up to date

Comment: done that ...updated to newest version. Its just working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update Joomla to 1.5.26, versions of Joomla older than 1.5.16 are not compatible with PHP 5.3+